# Can I use Spark prebuilt without hadoop on Windows?

Tags: windows, apache-spark, hadoop

I'm using Spark 3.1.3 prebuilt without Hadoop on a production unix based server. Spark is running in standalone mode. I'm using local filesystem rather than a distributed filesystem such as Hadoop.

I'd ideally like to replicate my production environment locally but unfortunately I'm restricted to using Windows.

Typically, I am able to run Spark on Windows by using Spark 3.1.3 prebuilt for Hadoop Y and using the winutils tool provided here: https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils

It's my understanding that winutils is simulating Hadoop rather than a unix FS.

Am I able to use the exact same Spark binaries in production and on my Windows development machine? Or am I restricted to using Spark prebuilt for Hadoop locally?

Can you explain why either solution works?

I tried running my Spark scripts locally using the version prebuilt without Hadoop but I'm unable to start my scripts. (Will provide some logs and edit this when I'm back on my Windows machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Without" only refers to the scripts/libraries in the downloaded tarball. The more correct term would be "bring your own Hadoop". You will still need `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` + `HADOOP_HOME` set, as well as HDFS client JAR libraries to use a local FS.

Yes, you can use Spark on Windows by including the correct version of Winutils. Or you can use WSL2 and download Spark within a full Unix environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does this mean I'll also need to "bring my own hadoop" in the Unix environment? Or use binaries which have it built in?

Comment: "Bring your own" means you already have Hadoop running elsewhere. Without that, then you should use the Spark version "with Hadoop"